# Cartthrob create_user 'your not authorised to perform this action' upon login

Tags: cartthrob, members, login

After using the **create_user** tag during my cartthrob checkout process, a user is created.

Now when logging into the site, the message **your not authorised to perform this action** shows and I cannot login as the created user.

I can be sure that the user is created with the correct password using cartthrob debugging output and also by trying to login with an incorrect password I get rejected with the incorrect password message.

The only way Im able to get the account to sign in is by using the super-admin members panel and changing the password...

Is it possible that when cartthrob is inserting the user, that something isn't going in correctly?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be a problematic entry into the sessions table by CartThrob, so removing it was a quick fix.

This is within the order confirmation cartthrob tab(post-payment).

(You need output stage php enabled, as {member_id} is a CartThrob tag)

db->delete(
      'exp_sessions',
         array(
           'member_id' => '{member_id}'
         )
      );
?>